# How to get Atrribute from Table

Tags: java, javascript, dom

I have the below table

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th col="value2"></th>
    </tr>
   </thead>
  <tbody>
     <tr id="value1">
       <td></td>
      </tr>
   </tbody
<table>
```

I use the below to get "value1" from `<tr>`

```
"row_id": this.parentNode.getAttribute('id')
```

I am trying to use the below to get col value from `<th>` but its returning a null value.

```
"colName": this.getAttribute('col')
```

How would I correctly get the col attribute value from `<th>` ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this dom function:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("th")[0].getAttribute("col");
```

Comment: Thanks for that. Is it possible to use it with out specifying the array number?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
      console.log($('table thead tr th').attr('col'));

});
```

this will give the first tr what you can do is check rowcount or using foreach loop

Comment: Thanks, but that also returns a null value.

Comment: Thanks, that works for the first value, but if I have multiple <tr>'s it will still only return the first value.

Comment: use foreach loop in jquery